# android index.android.bundle file

Tags: android, arm, arm64

I downloaded an app from Raccoon.
I got these files:

```
com.company.name-3423.apk
config.ar-3423.apk
config.armeabi_v7a-3423.apk
config.en-3423.apk
config.iw-3423.apk
config.ru-3423.apk
config.xhdpi-3423.apk
```

I used apktool to get the smali code from `com.company.name-3423.apk`.
I searched for a string that I saw in the app's UI. I found it only in the `index.android.bundle` file.

1. Are the apk files I downloaded part of an AAB file? If so, how do I build an AAB file from them?

2 - what is the `index.android.bundle` file? Is there a way to make it more readable so I can edit it and sign the app again?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Android's [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool). As Google explains, on [building an AAB with bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build), it may be helpful "to convert your app's compiled code and resources into app bundles".